# How to check if Data is null before inserting into Datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I discovered that at some point. There might be a null value. so I want to check if Data is null and redirect to the previous page before inserting into datatable.

I couldn't figure that out

This is what I have tried

```
$('#exceptionIntLoad').DataTable({
  pageLength: 10,
  ajax: {
    url: '/ExceptionInterest/GetCalculatedExceptionReport/' + id,
    dataSrc: '',
    success: function (result) {
      console.log("This is result", result)
      if (result == null) {
        return
      }
      else {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
          buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
          ],
            columns: [
              {
                title: 'Account No',
                data: 'accountNo'

              },
              {
                title: 'Start Balance',
                data: 'loanStartBalance'
              },
              {
                title: 'New Balance',
                data: 'newBalance'
              }
            ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Does this code work for you? Do you talk about code refactoring? Please be more specific. In general, your code throws errors (Fix the code):  https://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Answer (score 0):

Your already done this

check this part of code

success: function (result) {

```
                 console.log("This is result", result)


                 if (result == null) {


                     return


                 }
```

Here you can apply condition like if result!=null then you can call insert query

Comment: I am having an error at the sem-colon after button and columns ( buttons: columns: ) Unexpected ;

Answer (score 0):

To cover multiple falsy scenarios you should do it like this

```
success: function (result) {
                     console.log("This is result", result)
                     if (!result) {
                         return
                     }
                     else {
```